# Labeling Y axis with PChart

Tags: php, pchart

I am using **PChart for PHP** to draw graphs, it is working pretty well.

I have drawn a graph with intensities (2 = strong, 1 = medium, 0 = low) and I would like to know if is possible to show on the **Y axis the description of the data** (strong,medium,low) instead of the inappropriate numbers (2,1,0).

(I have search a lot without success, theoretically you can only set the X labels according to http://pchart.sourceforge.net/documentation.php?topic=faq.xlabels.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a way of assigning Y formats.  Currently there are 5: Number, Time, Date, Metric and Currency.  You set this in the pData class by using the function `SetYAxisFormat($Format)`

What you would have to do to acheive what you want is to modify the pChart.class file and include your own formatter function.

In various places in the `pChart.class` file, there is the following section of code:

```
   if ( $DataDescription["Format"]["Y"] == "number" )

    $Value = $Value.$DataDescription["Unit"]["Y"];

   if ( $DataDescription["Format"]["Y"] == "time" )

    $Value = $this->ToTime($Value);        

   if ( $DataDescription["Format"]["Y"] == "date" )

    $Value = $this->ToDate($Value);        

   if ( $DataDescription["Format"]["Y"] == "metric" )

    $Value = $this->ToMetric($Value);        

   if ( $DataDescription["Format"]["Y"] == "currency" )

    $Value = $this->ToCurrency($Value);
```

To add your own intensity function, after this bit you would need to add:

```
   if ( $DataDescription["Format"]["Y"] == "intensity" )
    $Value = $this->ToIntensity($Value);
```

Then you would need to add your own `ToIntensity($Value)` function inside the class:

```
function ToIntensity($Value)
    {

     switch($Value) {
       case 0:
       return "low";
       break;
       case 1:
       return "medium";
       break;
       case 2:
       return "strong";
       break;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Too good answer. I feel guilty for such a easy to implement answer. Thank you very much! It worked like charm.

Comment: +1 - a great answer deserving of more votes. Too bad pChart has a low profile on SO!